# SQL merge functionality without specifying column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, dynamic-sql

I'm doing a SQLBulkCopy from my web app and inserting the records into a staging table. This is my first time working with staging tables. The live table that will be accepting the data has about 200 fields and can change into the future. When this change occurs I didn't want to have to re-write the merge statement.

I came up with this SQL that mimics the merge functionality, but doesn't require me to spell out the table columns. I am not an SQL expert and wanted someone that is to take a look and let me know if you see any problems that could arise by using this SQL because I haven't seen any examples of this and many people searching.

Note that records in the staging table that have a null id field are to be inserted.

```
-- set the table names, primary key field & vars to hold query parts
DECLARE @LiveTable varchar(20) = 'Test'
DECLARE @StagingTable varchar(20) = 'TestStaging'
DECLARE @PKField varchar(20) = 'TestPK'
DECLARE @SQLSet nvarchar(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @SQLInsertFields nvarchar(MAX) = ''

-- get comma delimited field names
DECLARE @Fields nvarchar(MAX) = (SELECT dbo.fn_GetCommaDelimitedFieldNames(@LiveTable))

-- loop through fields generating set clause of query to execute
WHILE LEN(@Fields) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Field varchar(50) = left(@Fields, CHARINDEX(',', @Fields+',')-1)
    IF @Field <> @PKField -- the primary key field cannot be updated
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLSet += ', ' + @LiveTable + '.' + @Field + ' = ' + @StagingTable + '.' + @Field
            SET @SQLInsertFields += ', ' + @Field
        END
    SET @Fields = STUFF(@Fields, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @Fields+','), '')
END

-- remove the leading comma
SET @SQLSet = SUBSTRING(@SQLSet,3,LEN(@SQLSet))
SET @SQLInsertFields = SUBSTRING(@SQLInsertFields,3,LEN(@SQLInsertFields))

-- update records from staging table where primary key is provided
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'UPDATE ' + @LiveTable + 
                             ' SET ' + @SQLSet + 
                             ' FROM ' + @LiveTable + 
                             ' INNER JOIN ' + @StagingTable + 
                             ' ON ' + @LiveTable + '.' + @PKField + ' = ' + @StagingTable + '.' + @PKField

-- insert records from staging table where primary key is null
SET @SQL += '; INSERT INTO ' + @LiveTable + ' (' + @SQLInsertFields + ') SELECT ' + @SQLInsertFields + ' FROM ' + @StagingTable + ' WHERE ' + @PKField + ' IS NULL'

-- delete the records from the staging table
SET @SQL += '; DELETE FROM ' + @StagingTable

-- execute the sql statement to update existing records and insert new records
exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If anyone see's any issues with performance or anything else, I appreciate the insight.

Comment: You probably want to do this as a transaction so you don't get an error on insert or update than then delete your staging table.

Comment: @Hogan - Good point, will definitely put into a transaction. Thanks for your input.

Comment: 200 fields in one table?  Is relational or a flat file?

Comment: @Dan - There is some relational data. The table is a MLS listings table holding data such as price, sqft, beds, baths, etc. It's actually about 175 fields that make up the attributes all property types share as well as some back office data such as agent info, sale provisions, etc... Data that is not common between all property types have been normalized out to their own tables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.  Really.  You're working very hard to avoid a rare problem that you probably won't handle correctly when the time comes.

If the target table changes, how do you know it will change in such a way that your fancy dynamic SQL will work correctly?  How can you be sure it won't *seem* to work -- i.e. will work, syntactically -- but actually do the wrong thing?  If and when the target table changes, won't you have to change your application, and the staging table too?  With all that in the air, what's adding one more `SET` clause?

In the meanwhile, how can anyone be expected to read that gobbledygook (not your fault, really, that's SQL's syntax)?  A bog-standard insert statement would be very clear and dependable.

And fast.  SQL Server can't optimize your dynamic query.  You used bcp for efficiency, and now you're defeating it with well meaning futureproofingness.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it will be highly considered. I'll be testing the performance of this vs the MERGE and if there are big differences, I'll go that route and manually keep up the MERGE statement. I can't think of a scenario where this wouldn't execute correctly, perhaps you can provide an example? There's a trigger that keeps the staging table's structure in sync with the target table so there wouldn't be an issue there. If the target table changes, the only change in my app would be to update the EntityModel, but no code changes because the mapping from the source is dynamic.